Nginx ssl_client_certificate and ssl_verify_client on: specify client cert or client CA cert?
This is for enabling mutual ssl in nginx.
I have 3 files for the client's certificate: client.pem, client.ca.pem, and client.bundle.pem. (bundle has client first, ca 2nd)
Which of these files do I use for the ssl_client_certificate setting?  I thought it would be the bundle but from looking at the docs it doesn't actually say which file to use.
# https://mysite.example.com
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/ssl/client/client.bundle.pem;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
ssl_verify_depth 2;
# check the result of ssl client cert verify
add_header X-ssl_client_verify $ssl_client_verify always;
if ($ssl_client_verify != "SUCCESS") {
  return 403;
}

Because when I test the connection, I always get a 403.  The verify header is X-ssl_client_verify:"NONE" as well.
curl --cert client.pem --key client.key https://mysite.example.com

I have checked with a bash shell and the client certs are correctly in the /etc/ssl/client dir on the deployed site.
